# Prisma and Postgres FetchError: request to http://localhost:4466/management failed

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, prisma

I am trying to work with Prisma. I have tried the available solutions on GitHub issues and StackOverflow as well.

I have installed Prisma using the following Command

```
npm install -g prisma
```

I have docker and docker-compose installed in the system.

The following is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
 prisma:
   image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
   restart: always
   ports:
    - "4466:4466"
   environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
       port: 4466
       # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
       # managementApiSecret: my-secret
       databases:
         default:
           connector: postgres
           host: host.docker.internal
           database: db
           schema: public
           user: prisma
           password: prisma
           ssl: false
           rawAccess: true
           port: '5432'
           migrations: true
  postgres:
   image: postgres:11
   restart: always
   environment:
     POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
   volumes:
     - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres: ~
```

So, now I try to start my container by using the following command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Now, I check if the containers are running fine using the following command.

docker-compose ps

the following is the output

```
Name                        Command                         State   Ports         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
graphql-prisma_postgres_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up      5432/tcp              
graphql-prisma_prisma_1     /bin/sh -c /app/start.sh        Up      0.0.0.0:4466->4466/tcp
```

Now, If I try to execute the following

```
prisma deploy
docker-compose ps
```

the following is the output

```
environment FetchError: request to http://localhost:4466/management failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4466
environment     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/tomonso/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1393:11)
environment     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:200:13)
environment     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
environment     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:402:9)
environment     at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
environment     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
environment     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
environment     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
environment     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9) +0ms
environment FetchError: request to http://localhost:4466/management failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4466
environment     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/tomonso/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1393:11)
environment     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:200:13)
environment     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
environment     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:402:9)
environment     at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
environment     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
environment     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
environment     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
environment     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9) +3ms
command Failed to fetch server version +0ms
command TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null +0ms
environment FetchError: request to http://localhost:4466/management failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4466
environment     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/tomonso/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1393:11)
environment     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:200:13)
environment     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
environment     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:402:9)
environment     at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
environment     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
environment     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
environment     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
environment     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9) +4ms
environment FetchError: request to http://localhost:4466/management failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4466
environment     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/tomonso/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1393:11)
environment     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:200:13)
environment     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
environment     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:402:9)
environment     at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
environment     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
environment     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
environment     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
environment     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9) +1ms
Error: Could not connect to server at http://localhost:4466. Please check if your server is running.
at Deploy.<anonymous> (/home/tomonso/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_mod 
ules/prisma-cli-core/src/commands/deploy/deploy.ts:137:13)
at step (/home/tomonso/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/prisma-cli-core/dist/commands/deploy/deploy.js:45:23)
at Object.next (/home/tomonso/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/prisma-cli-core/dist/commands/deploy/deploy.js:26:53)
at fulfilled (/home/tomonso/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_mod 
ules/prisma-cli-core/dist/commands/deploy/deploy.js:17:58)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
(node:25136) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: 
OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
 util timed out +0ms
  output Exiting with code: 0 +0ms
```

Comment: how did you set postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

First if you use `docker logs` to check the prisma log, you will find a lots of errors. And there are several issues here:

1. `host.docker.internal` just works on docker for mac/docker for windows.

   If above is your truth, then you want to use `host machine's 5432 port` to visit `postgres's 5342 port`. If this, you need to specify port mapping `- "5432:5432"` in `postgres service`.

   If you just work on linux, then `host.docker.internal` even not recognized.

   In fact, no matter you use windows/mac/linux, you just need to replace `host: host.docker.internal` with `host: postgres`, the `prisma container` could directly visit `postgres container`, no need host machine's intervene, you can refers to [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge), search `User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers` for more help in that page.
2. when `prisma service` want to setup `db` database, the `postgres service` even haven't start yet, you need to define start order to assure the `postgres service` ready before `prisma service`, you can refers to [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/):

   But, if you have a look for its entrypoint, you can see next:

   ```
   bash-4.4# cat start.sh
   #!/bin/bash
   set -e
   /app/prerun_hook.sh
   /app/bin/prisma-local
   ```

   Here, `/app/prerun_hook.sh` is a hook for user who use this image to do some pre-things, so you can just add some service start assure code in this file to assure the db service start already.

Finally, a workable solution is next:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            database: db
            schema: public
            user: prisma
            password: prisma
            ssl: false
            rawAccess: true
            port: '5432'
            migrations: true
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11
    restart: always
     environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
   postgres: ~
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
COPY ./prerun_hook.sh /app/prerun_hook.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/prerun_hook.sh && \
    apk add postgresql-client
```

**prerun_hook.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

until PGPASSWORD="prisma" psql -h postgres -U "prisma" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
```

Then, if check docker logs you will see next which means it's ok now:

```
Postgres is up - executing command
No log level set, defaulting to INFO.
[INFO] {} - Starting...
[INFO] {} - Start completed.
[INFO] Initializing workers...
[INFO] Obtaining exclusive agent lock...
[INFO] Obtaining exclusive agent lock... Successful.
[INFO] Successfully started 1 workers.
[INFO] Deployment worker initialization complete.
Server running on :4466
```